# How ro read a lot of csv indexed files

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have 38 `.csv` files, named `Raw_data_unique_1` to `Raw_data_unique_38`, and all have the same column structure.

I would like to read these files using the instruction I know `pd.read_csv` and then append all of them in `1` unique file, say, `data_unique`.

So, I create a list of indexes: `lst = list(range(1,39))` and thougt I could just run:

```
for i in lst:
    data_i = pd.read_csv('C:/.../Raw_data_unique_i.csv', sep=',', header=0)
```

But there is a misunderstanding on my part: the name `Raw_data_unique_i.csv` is not recognized: "*[Errno 2] No such file or directory*", which means no number is assigned to index `i`...

Could you explain me what I did wrong?

Comment: A normal string is just a string, variable names in it aren't processed in a particular way. You can e. g. use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Pandas for this operation

```
import shutil

with open('data_unique.csv', 'w') as out:
    for i in range(1, 40):
        with open(f'Raw_data_unique_{i}.csv') as inp:
            shutil.copyfileobj(inp, out)
```

Here I used [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) to evaluate `i` inside the string. If you use Python < 3.6, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```
with open('Raw_data_unique_{i}.csv'.format(i=i)) as inp:
```

Comment: Nice job! `shutil` was unknown to me...

Answer (score 0):

Your "i" isn't a variable in the name like this.

Maybe a quick ficx would be declaring:

```
folder = 'C:/.../Raw_data_unique_'
format = csv
```

and then concatenate

```
file_name = folder+i+format
data_i = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',', header=0)
```

But remember that if you need to work each data_i during the loop iteration because it would be rewritten everytime. If you dont want that, you should look into the structure you have and find a way to better store it.

ps.: if you only want to limit your for iteration:

```
for i in range(1, 39):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an f-string to make `i` inside the string take the actual value of the variable `i`:

```
for i in lst:
    data_i = pd.read_csv(f'C:/.../Raw_data_unique_{i}.csv', sep=',', header=0)
```

Note the `f` before the string and the `{i}` inside the string.